# SAF (Storage access network) custom options

Tags: android, storage, saf

I am using the Storage Access Framework (SAF) :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("image/svg+xml");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

I am using the following extra:

```
intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
```

My question is, where this extras to configure certain SAF options are documented?
I want to display filenames as default, because thumbs cannot show preview for svg files and it's confusing (and that's the default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> where this extras to configure certain SAF options are documented?

Most are not documented. The few that are will be documented either [on `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT) or will appear as other defined constants [on `Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent).

And, as always, using undocumented `Intent` extras may lead to inconsistent behavior across devices and OS versions, as Google is not considering those extras to be part of a public, supported API.

Comment: ok, I don't understand how some things in Android are so well documented and others are like this. I have no clue about how to accomplish displaying filenames as default.

Comment: @takluiper: In this case, my guess is that they are not documented because they are not supposed to be a public API. Similarly, `android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED` is not part of the public API. You are welcome to try it, but your results may or may not be what you expect, across the range of Android device models and versions.